# problemas para salir de git commit

Tags: git-commit

Hola entre a la consola de git commit pero no una vez que ingrese no puedo salir de ahi, estoy aprendiendo pero varios videos y paginas dice que se sale con :q o :wq pero nada, gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Prueba con darle a la tecla `Esc` antes de escribir el `:q`, quizás estas aun en modo edición (eso si es el VI/VIM o sucedaneos... si es otro ni idea)

Comment: No hay una "consola de git commit". Lo que hace git es abrirte el editor de texto preconfigurado en tu sistema, para que desde ese editor escribas el mensaje de commit. Por tanto lo que ves en la "consola" es tu editor, y para saber cómo salir de él deberíamos saber qué editor es. Habitualmente se trata del editor "vim". Si es ese el caso, puedes pulsar ESC varias veces para asegurarte de que estás en modo comando y después escribir `:q!` para salir sin guardar cambios. Si ya tienes un prompt abajo con los dos puntos, basta que pongas `q`

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola tengo el mismo problema lo descargue con el editor nano y no me abre la bandeja de para guardarlo tuve q salir y perdi todo pq es esto? o hay una nueva version q no se usar, igual no soy ningun experto

Answer (score 1):

Si te sale la consola de git commit es porque hay conflictos por resolver pero para mi experiencia es un poco locura. Para poder salir de allí y que siga con su trayectoria del commit y después resuelves los conflictos tienes que poner **:qa** saldrás.

Después con Visual studio o con algún programa de Git resuelves los conflictos.

Comment: quería escribir un mensaje con git commit pero lo hice del metodo normal en vez de la alternativa git commit -m "mensaje", ahora me quede en esa consola y ya no puedo salir

Comment: Qué consola estás usando?

Comment: Ami siemrpe que me salen las consolas la hacer un commit pongo eso **:qa** para salir